# ValueInjecter Mapping ViewModel To Domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, valueinjecter

I am playing around with valueinjecter and wondering how do I do viewmodels to domains when the view model has a collection of viewmodels?

Say I have this domain

```
   public class MyDomain
   {
       public IList<MyOtherDomain> MyOtherDomains {get; set;}
   }

   public class MyOtherDomain
   {
       public string Name {get; set;}
   }

   public class MyMasterVM
   {
       public IList<MyOtherVm> MyOtherDomains {get; set;}
   }    

   public class MyOtherVm
   {
       public string Name {get; set;}
   }
```

now how do I do my injecting? Do I need to manually map these with valueinjector?

```
public ActionResult Method(MyMasterVM vm)
{
   MyDomain d = new MyDomain();
    d.InjectFrom<UnflatLoopValueInjection>(vm);
}
```

**Edit**

After some playing around I got the simulator to work. However mine is different than the one in the tests

```
// sample test
   public class FooBar : TypeMapper<Foo, Bar>
        {
            public override Bar Map(Foo source, Bar target)
            {
                base.Map(source, target);
                target.NoConvention = source.Name + source.Xyz + source.Props;
                return target;
            }
        }

             [Test]
    public void MapShouldMapCollectionPropertiesAndUseFooBarTypeMapper()
    {
        MapperFactory.AddMapper(new FooBar());
        var foo = new Foo
        {
            Foos = new List<Foo>
                       {
                           new Foo{Name = "f1",Props = "v",Xyz = 19},
                           new Foo{Name = "f2",Props = "i",Xyz = 7},
                           new Foo{Name = "f3",Props = "v",Xyz = 3},
                       }
        };

        var bar = Mapper.Map<Foo, Bar>(foo);

        Assert.AreEqual(foo.Foos.Count(), bar.Foos.Count());

        var ffoos = foo.Foos.ToArray();
        var bfoos = bar.Foos.ToArray();

        for (var i = 0; i < ffoos.Count(); i++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(ffoos[i].Name, bfoos[i].Name);
            Assert.AreEqual(ffoos[i].Name + ffoos[i].Xyz + ffoos[i].Props, bfoos[i].NoConvention);
        }
    }

        // mine
public class Test : TypeMapper<IList<MyOtherVm>, IList<MyOtherDomain>> 
    {
        public override IList<MyOtherDomain> Map(IList<MyOtherVm> source, IList<MyOtherDomain> target)
        {
            // not sure if I always have to call base
            // mapping would happen here.
            return base.Map(source, target);
        }
    }

       MapperFactory.AddMapper(new Test());
            IList<MyOtherDomain> otherDomains= new List<MyOtherDomain>();
           MapperVj.Map(vm.MyOtherDomains , otherDomains);
```

I have to specify it is a IList otherwise it never seems to go into my overridden method.

Comment: Is the type of MyDomain.MyOtherDomains correct? Should it be `IList<MyOtherDomain>`

Comment: @chobo2 You didn't had to create your Test :TypeMapper, just do Mapper.Map

Comment: new TypeMapper is needed only when you have a mapping that doesn't fit into any convention (hence the test class Property Name "NoConvention")

Comment: I did a new test project that you can download, it uses your classes also, get it here: http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/releases/view/60311#DownloadId=318259

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd need to implement your own custom `IValueInjection` injector. I am also basing this answer on a typo in your `MyDomain` class.

### Assumption of typo:

```
MyDomain.MyOtherDomains : IList<MyOtherDomains>
```

and not

```
MyDomain.MyOtherDomains : IList<MyOtherVm>
```

So, the customer injection class could look like this (not 100% if there's a better way to do it)

```
public class CustomInjecter : IValueInjection
{
    public object Map(object source, object target)
    {
        MyDomain result = new MyDomain();
        result.MyOtherDomains = new List<MyOtherDomain>();

        foreach (MyOtherVm vm in (source as MyMasterVM).MyOtherVMs)
        {
            MyOtherDomain od = new MyOtherDomain();
            // inject commonly named properties of each "child" VM
            od.InjectFrom(vm);
            result.MyOtherDomains.Add(od);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

In your controller, you can use it almost like you specified above (just change the injector type)

```
public ActionResult Method(MyMasterVM vm)
{
    MyDomain d = new MyDomain();
    d.InjectFrom<CustomInjecter>(vm);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Typo corrected....So is this just because it is in a collection? I have a property Called IssuerName that would be Issuer.Name and it has no problem doing those ones.

Comment: @chobo2 I'm not *certain* this has to be done because it's a collection. It's just the basic way of writing your own custom `ValueInjection`. There may be some more elegant way that I don't see in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

one quick and easy way would be to do this:

```
MyDomain.MyOtherDomains =
vm.MyOtherDomains.Select(o => new MyOtherDomain().InjectFrom(o))
.Cast<MyOtherDomain>();
```

**edit:**
I did a new test project that you can download (it uses your classes also).
get it here: http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/releases/view/60311#DownloadId=318259

Comment: I will try that. Is this just because I have a collection of these?

Comment: @chobo2 it's 2 properties of 2 different types, IEnumerable<MyOtherDomain> and IEnumerable<MyOtherVm>, the default InjectFrom() will not affect them, so you either to do it manually or use an injection that does something, there's a more generic one for collection in the "Automapper simulation" on codeplex site, EnumerabelTypeMapper<T1,T2> which will involve using a custom Mapper class, you can look at the unit tests at the bottom and see how it works http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Automapper%20Simulation&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Your code seems not to work since MyDomain.MyOtherDomains is a IList collection and your select returns IEnumerable<object>. I tried to do ToList but still does not work.

Comment: Do you recommend then to use the automapper simulation then?

Comment: I tried the simulator but it I got a error. Let me grab it when I can. I will also try your cast thing.

Comment: Ok that does not cause it to crash but it does not bind anything. So not sure how to debug it and figure out why it does not bind. I made sure the names are the same.

Comment: Maybe I am not using the automapper simulator right. I don't get this //FooBar is a class that implements ITypeMapper<TSource,TTarget> ( inherit the base class TypeMapper<TSource, TTarget> and add additional mapping code). Do I have to have a method or something that does the mapping manually? Do I have to override the Map method?